# Cython for loop conversion

Tags: python, cython

Using `cython -a`, I found that a `for i in range(0, a, b)` statement was run as a python loop (very yellow line in `cython -a` html output). `i`, `a` and `b` were `cdef`-ed as `int64_t`.

Then I tried the 'old' syntax `for i from 0 <= i < b by a`. From the output of `cython -a` it seemed to compile quite optimal as expected.

Is it expected behaviour that range(0, a, b) is not optimized here or is this rather bound to the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Automatic range conversion](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/pyrex_differences.html#automatic-range-conversion) is only applied when cython can determine the sign of the step at compile time. As the step in this case is a signed type it cannot and so falls back to the python loop.

Note that currently even when the type is unsigned cython still falls back onto the python loop, this is a (rather old) outstanding further optimisation that the compiler could do but doesn't. Have a look at this ticket for more information:

http://trac.cython.org/ticket/546